# How to enable Edit and Continue in Visual Studio 

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I was using Visual Studio 2010 Express for a project and recently changed over to ultimate 2010.  I am noticing that when I would debug in express I could put a break point, edit the code if needed and continue without having to recompile.

With VS 2010 ultimate it tells me the version has changed and i have to stop and restart.  How do i get the functionality that express had in ultimate?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:  More specifically, here is the message i get:
"This source file has changed.  It no longer matches the versio nof the file used to build the application being debugged".

Comment: For all the money you shelled out with for the Ultimate edition, a quick scan through the options should be well worth your time, to be honest.

Comment: Who do you report a condescending moderator to? Quis custodiet?

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable 'Edit & Continue' both in the debug menu (should be on by default. check by going to debug > options+settings)  and possibly again in the specific project if it's a web project of some sort.  It should be a checkbox there.

edit: it's been a bit since i've tried it, but as far as i recall, that's the how. i'll see if i can grab you a link.

Comment: WOW.  I didn't even get my edit in there and you responded.  excellent. If i try it now i get:  Changes are not allowed in the following cases:  whn the debugger has been attached to an already running process.  - the code being debugged was optimized at build or run time.  - the assembly being debugged is loaded as domain-neutral.  - the assembly being debugged was loaded through reflection.    I am a novice developer and these sound foreign to me.

Comment: The error you posted can be caused by a bunch of things.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx  Here's the main MSDN for the feature.  If you're doing something fancy DLLs or IIS, that might also be causing you trouble so I would suggest clearing your temp files after enabling E+C then rebuilding fresh before trying it

Comment: As to your edit in the comment, the best I could find for you was https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553406/edit-and-continue-message-does-not-specify-intellitrace-settings

Comment: I also had to disable the option "Enable optimizations" under
Right click on project=>Properties=>Compile=>Advanced Compile Options...